# Python add new colum to dataframe with groupby

Tags: python

I have time-series for multiple groups. I would like to add a new column with the value corresponding to the latest date in each group.

I have tried:

df.groupby('GROUP', as_index = False).apply(lambda x: x[x['DATE'] == valuation_date]['VALUE'].values[0]))

and this produces a new table with the values I needd. However, I can`t find a way to directly add these values to each group in the original dataframe.

Any help will be appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign the output to a new column in your DataFrame.

If I wanted to create a new column called `animal_mean_speed` I would do something like the [documentation demonstrates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                              'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})
df
   Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1  Falcon      370.0
2  Parrot       24.0
3  Parrot       26.0
df.groupby(['Animal']).mean()
        Max Speed
Animal
Falcon      375.0
Parrot       25.0
```

To add the aggregate value we just computed to each row of the original DataFrame we need to assign the value. Aggregate functions like groupby generally produce output that breaks normalization. It can make sense when outputting data for presentation but I would recommend using other utilities like `join()` if you plan to perform further analysis. If we want to join the computed `mean()` to our original DataFrame we can. Here is one way using `merge()` where all the values in the first DataFrame are returned, [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html#left-outer-join),

```
>>> pd.merge(df.set_index('Animal'), df_mean, on="Animal", how="left")
                Max Speed_x  Max Speed_y
>>> Animal
>>> Falcon        380.0        375.0
>>> Falcon        370.0        375.0
>>> Parrot         24.0         25.0
>>> Parrot         26.0         25.0

>>> df_output.rename(columns={"Max Speed_y": "animal_mean_speed"})
        Max Speed_x  animal_mean_speed
Animal
Falcon        380.0              375.0
Falcon        370.0              375.0
Parrot         24.0               25.0
Parrot         26.0               25.0
```

I frequently forget how to perform this operation so here are some useful troubleshooting tips for joining two DataFrames:

- Double check a DataFrame's index with `df.index`. This can help when deciding whether multiple DataFrames are using the index you expect them to use. Notice how the two DataFrame's have different indices in the output below.

```
>>> df.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)
>>> df_mean.index
Index(['Falcon', 'Parrot'], dtype='object', name='Animal')
```

- `df.set_index()` can help you be explicit about what columns you are using as the join keys.
- Always remember the difference between [copy vs in-place operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html#copies-vs-in-place-operations) and when in doubt, copy values and create a new object.
- Take a look at the [aggregate statistics](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/06_calculate_statistics.html#aggregating-statistics-grouped-by-category) section of the Pandas Documentation